# What does following hql query mean

Tags: sql, hql

```
order by
   (case when CAR.DRIVER is null then 1 else 0 end),
   CAR.DRIVER, CAR.NAME
```

Comment: if there is no driver let it sit on the bottom of the list then alphanumerically by driver and name.

Answer (score 2):

This query sorts looking **first** if the car has a driver. In case that the car has a driver, the query returns `0`. This means that the cars that have a driver will **appear first** on the results.

After that, it's a normal sort using the car's driver and the car's name.